# referring a range of cells inside a for loop in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code like below.I am trying to calculate nth business day after a specified date mentioned in ColA.I am having list of holidays in ColB(B1:B20).I am getting stuck on how to refer these holidays in a FOR loop in the place of XXX.

```
For i=1 to m
cells(i,"c").Value=workday(cells(i,"A").Value,n,XXX)
next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the Range in place.

```
For i=1 to m
cells(i,"c").Value = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(cells(i,"A").Value,n,[B1:B20])
next i
```

Or if you will be doing a lot of loops might be useful to fill the dates in an array

```
Dim Holidays As Variant
Holidays = [B1:B10]

For i=1 to m
cells(i,"c").Value = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(cells(i,"A").Value,n,Holidays)
next i
```

***UPDATE:*** This is the test I did based on your comment, can you explain what is wrong?

[image]

So 5 workdays from March 1st, 2013 would be March 8th, 2013:

1. March 4th
2. March 5th
3. March 6th
4. March 7th
5. March 8th

   and of all the holidays in my list (random days) only 1 falls between the 1st and the 8th,
   `3/4/2013`. So because of that it changes the result to March 11th. From your comment it sounds like you are saying your result would be: March 22nd, 5 buisness days plus 10 holidays, is this correct? As you can see I do not recieve that result. So, Maybe more details could help? Or maybe better for another question.

Comment: i am able to refer the holidays like u said.I am having one more problem.Suppose cell A3 contains a value 3/1/2013 and i want to find 5th business day after A3.but by referring the cells as you mentioned,it is taking all the holidays into account including those in Jan and Feb.But i want to take into account only if it falls between 3/1/2013 and 5th business day in march.is there any way to do like this?

Comment: @ManasaJ Added a sample, if you could reference your experiance against that maybe I will be able to better understand your problem.

Comment: Looks like I have miscalculated some thing.I wanted 5th business day.so I should have given 4 as parameter in workday function.Since I gave one day extra,I misunderstood that the holiday I mentioned in jan was taken into account.what you said was absolutely correct..